# How to mark co-ordinates of points in Octave using "plot" command?

Tags: matlab, gnuplot, octave

I am using the `plot` command in Octave to plot `y` versus `x` values. Is there a way such that the graph also shows the `(x,y)` value of every coordinate plotted on the graph itself?

I've tried using the `help` command but I couldn't find any such option.

Also, if it isn't possible, is there a way to do this using any other plotting function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried displaying a text box at each coordinate?

Assuming `x` and `y` are co-ordinates already stored in MATLAB, you could do something like this:

```
plot(x, y, 'b.');
for i = 1 : numel(x) %// x and y are the same lengths
    text(x(i), y(i), ['(' num2str(x(i)) ',' num2str(y(i)) ')']);
end
```

The above code will take each point in your graph and place a text box (with no borders) in the format of `(x,y)` where x and y are the coordinates for all of the points.

**Note:**  You may have to play around with the position of the text boxes, because the above code will place each text box right on top of each pair of co-ordinates.  You can play around by adding/subtracting appropriate constants in the first and second parameters of the `text` function. (i.e. `text(x(i) + 1, y(i) - 1, .......);`  However, if you want something quick and for illustrative purposes, then the above code will be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I've used to do something similar. Generating the strings for the labels is the most awkward part, really (I only had a single number per label, which is a lot simpler)

```
x = rand(1, 10);
y = rand(1, 10);
scatter(x, y);

% create a text object for each point
t = text(x, y, '');

% generate a cell array of labels - x and y must be row vectors in this case
c = strsplit(sprintf('%.2g,%.2g\n',[x;y]), '\n');
c(end) = [];  % the final \n gives us an extra empty cell, remove it
c = c';  % transpose to match the dimensions of t

% assign each label to each text object
set(t, {'String'}, c);
```

You may want to play around with various properties like `'HorizontalAlignment'`, `'VerticalAlignment'` and `'Margin'` to tweak the label positions to your liking.

---

After a little more thought, here's an alternative, more robust way to generate a suitable cell array of coordinate labels:

```
c = num2cell([x(:) y(:)], 2);
c = cellfun(@(x) sprintf('%.2g,%.2g',x), c, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very useful package [labelpoints](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46891-labelpoints)
in MathWorks File Exchange that does exactly that.
It has a lot of convenient features.